# React Native: synchronously run functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, es6-promise

I'm new to OOP. My knowledge of promises/asynchronously/synchronously running functions is simply basic. I'd really appreciate your time and attention!

This is the example from React-Native docs:

```js
async function getMoviesFromApi() {
    try {
      let response = await fetch('https://facebook.github.io/react-native/movies.json');
      let responseJson = await response.json();
      return responseJson.movies;
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
```

As i understand from code above, getMoviesFromApi is declared as async function. which means it will execute functions one after other. Right? please correct me if not!

it will first wait for fetch to finish then call response.json, right?

I have few functions, which get data from a server via fetch, then insert them to sqlite database. so they don't return anything.

in example above, fetch returns something. but my functions, not. so, can i use this structure to make javascript run my functions consequently? what is the best practice / right solution to achieve this?

```js
let query = [];
export default class Main extends Component(){
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
  }
  
  componentWillMount(){
    this.getBookable();
    this.getBooked();
    this.runQuery();
    this.redirectUser();
    //// i need this functions to run consequently. not all in same time, one after eachother
  }
  
  getBookable(){
    let fetchedData = fetch(); /// Fetchs data from remote server
    query.push('INSERT INTO bookable (data) VALUES (' + fetchedData + ')');
  }
  
  getBooked(){
    let fetchedData = fetch(); /// Fetchs data from remote server
    query.push('INSERT INTO booked (data) VALUES (' + fetchedData + ')');
  }
  
  runQuery(){
    for(let i=0; i < query.length; i++){
      db.transaction((tx) => {
        tx.executeSql(query[i],[], (tx, results) => {
            console.log('Query', query[f], 'Executed. results:', results);
        }, (err)=>{
            console.log('Something went wrong while executing query',query[i],'error is', err);
          });
      });
    }
  }
  
  redirectUser(){
    Actions.tabbar({type: 'reset'});
    //// Using redux. redirect user to another page
  }
  
}
```

First, i get bookable courses, then booked courses, insert them to database, then redirect user to another page via redux
How should i update my code?

---

UPDATE :

updated code according to @Bergi :
is this the right way?

```js
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {
  ActivityIndicator,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NetInfo,
  AlertIOS,
} from 'react-native';

var SQLite = require('react-native-sqlite-storage');
var Loading = require("./Loading");
var DeviceInfo = require('react-native-device-info');
import { Actions } from 'react-native-router-flux';
var LOADING = {};
var db = SQLite.openDatabase({name : "oc.db", location: 'default'});
import CodePush from "react-native-code-push";
import I18n from 'react-native-i18n';
import translations from './translations';
I18n.fallbacks = true;

export default class Grab extends Component{
  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            terms: '',
            isLoading: false,
            isConnected: null,
            coursesFetched: false,
            registerFetched: false,
        };
    }

  componentWillMount() {

    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
      this.setState({
        isConnected: isConnected
      });
    });

    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
      'change',
      isConnected => {
        this.setState({
          isConnected: isConnected
        });
        console.log('Grab: internet status is', this.state.isConnected);
        this.sync();
      }
    );

    this.GrabData();

  }

  toggleAllowRestart() {
    this.state.restartAllowed
      ? CodePush.disallowRestart()
      : CodePush.allowRestart();

    this.setState({ restartAllowed: !this.state.restartAllowed });
  }

  sync() {
    console.log("Grab: Running manual code push update");
  CodePush.sync(
    {
      installMode: CodePush.InstallMode.IMMEDIATE,
      updateDialog: false
    },
  );
}

  async getUsers(){
    let userlist = [];
    let query = ["SELECT * FROM users"];
    await db.transaction(tx => {
      return Promise.all(query.map(async (q) => {
        try {
          let results = await tx.executeSql(q, []);
          console.log('Query', q, 'Executed. results:', results);
          for(let ind = 0; ind < len; ind++ ){
            userlist[ind] = {
              userId: results.rows.item(ind).userId,
              userName: results.rows.item(ind).userName,
              userMail: results.rows.item(ind).userMail,
              active: results.rows.item(ind).active,
              firstName: results.rows.item(ind).firstName,
              lastName: results.rows.item(ind).lastName,
              accessToken: results.rows.item(ind).access_token,
              host: results.rows.item(ind).host,
            };
          }
        } catch(err) {
          console.log('Something went wrong while executing query', q, 'error is', err);
        }
      }));
    });
    return userlist;
  }

  async getBookable(users){
    let results = [];
    for(let n=0; n < users.length; n++){
      try {
        let host = users[n].host;
        let access_token = users[n].access_token;
        let userId = users[n].userId;
        let response = await fetch(host + 'event/my_events', {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'language': DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale(),
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
          }
        });
        let responseData = await response.json();
        //// Get container details
        if(responseData.container.length > 0){
          for(let i=0; i < responseData.container.length; i++){
            let cnid = responseData.container[i].nid;
            let ctitle = responseData.container[i].title;
            results.push(
              "INSERT INTO containersC (userId, nid, title) VALUES ('" + userId + "','" + cnid + "', '" + ctitle + "')"
            );
            //// Get courses for each container
            for(let j=0; j < responseData.container[i].course.length; j++){
              let course_id = responseData.container[i].course[j].nid;
              let title = responseData.container[i].course[j].title;
              let cost = responseData.container[i].course[j].cost;
              let status = responseData.container[i].course[j].status;
              let period = responseData.container[i].course[j].period.time_sys;
              //// Get details for each course
              try {
                let resp = await fetch(host + 'event/course_detail/' + course_id, {
                  method: 'POST',
                  headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'language': DeviceInfo.getDeviceLocale(),
                    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + access_token
                  }
                });
                let respData = await resp.json();

                let desc = respData.data.content[0].value;
                let capacity = respData.data.content[1].value;
                let image = respData.data.image;
                let status = respData.data.book;
                let cancel = respData.data.cancel;
                let cd = responseData.data.dates;

                results.push(
                  "INSERT INTO courses (userId, course_id, container_nid, title, cost, status, period, desc, capacity, image, cancel) VALUES ('" + userId + "','" + course_id + "', '" + cnid + "', '" + title + "', '" + cost + "', '" + status + "', '" + period + "', '" + desc + "', '" + capacity + "', '" + image + "', '" + cancel + "')"
                );

                //// Getting lecture dates for each course
                for(let a=0; a < cd.length; a++){
                  let sdate = cd[a].start_time.split(" ");
                  let edate = cd[a].end_time.split(" ");
                  results.push(
                    "INSERT INTO lectures (userId, course_id, title, start_time, end_time, start_date, end_date, room, teacher) VALUES ('" + userId + "','" + course_id + "', '" + cd[a].title + "', '" + sdate[1] + "', '" + edate[1] + "', '" + sdate[0] + "', '" + edate[0] + "', '" + cd[a].room + "', '" + cd[a].teacher + "')"
                  );
                }
                //// End getting lecture dates for courses
                return true;
              } catch(error) {
                console.error(error);
              }
              //// End getting details for courses
            }
            //// End getting courses for containers
          }
        }
        //// End getting container details
        return true;
      } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
      }
    }
  }

  redirectUser(){
    Actions.tabbar({type: 'reset'});
  }

  async runQuery(query) {
    await db.transaction(tx => {
      return Promise.all(query.map(async (q) => {
        try {
          let results = await tx.executeSql(q, []);
          console.log('Query', q, 'Executed. results:', results);
        } catch(err) {
          console.log('Something went wrong while executing query', q, 'error is', err);
        }
      }));
    });
    return true;

  }

  async function GrabData(){
    try {
      let users = await getUsers();
      //let [courses, register, evaluation] = await Promise.all([getCourses(users), getRegister(users), getEvaluation(users)]);
      let [courses] = await Promise.all([getCourses(users)]);
      //let query = [courses, register, evaluation];
      let query = [courses];
      await runQuery(["DELETE FROM containersC", "DELETE FROM courses", "DELETE FROM lectures", "DELETE FROM containersR", "DELETE FROM register", "DELETE FROM lectures", "DELETE FROM evaluations", "DELETE FROM fields"]);
      await runQuery(query);
      this.redirectUser();
    } catch(error){
      console.log(error);
    }
  }


  render() {

return(
    <View style={styles.container}><Loading/></View>
  );
  }

}

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: "#fff",
      flexDirection: "column",
    },
});

Grab = CodePush(Grab);
```

I'm using react-native-sqlite-storage :
https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage

Comment: What is that `fetch` in your example?

Comment: You should not use a stateful `query` array. Instead, let the methods return their respective queries to be executed.

Comment: @Bergi that fetches json data from a remote server. i didnt write the whole function there, as i thought it's not necessary.

Comment: Shouldn't you put the loop *inside* the transaction to make sure the queries are getting evaluated sequentially?

Comment: So `fetch` is asynchronous? What exactly does it return?

Comment: @Bergi let me update the question

Comment: There are a lot of things going on in your code. I recommend to split this question into several ones because the response of this question it's going to be very broad, from the `async` JS keyword to how React Native works or the Redux architecture.

Comment: @amb currently my code is running, problem is user is being redirected to another page before execution of all queries finished. i think my problem is not about redux. my functions are running in same time, before previous ones finish. i'm looking for a solution for that

Comment: @Bergi i have updated the question with fetch

Comment: Thanks. Do `db.transaction` and `tx.executeSql` support callbacks or promises? What framework are you using, can you link its docs?

Comment: @Bergi , thanks for your answer, i have added details to last part of question. i'm using react-native-sqlite-storage

Comment: Ah, that seems to already support promises. I updated my answer with that part, though I'm not sure whether that's working as intended - the docs are a bit sparse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `getMoviesFromApi` is declared as `async function`. which means it will execute functions one after other.

No. That only means that it will return a promise when called, and that you can use the `await` operator in the function body.

> it will first wait for fetch to finish then call response.json, right?

Yes, because it uses `await` to stop evaluation of the method until the promise resolves.

> I have few functions, which get data from a server via fetch, then insert them to sqlite database. so they don't return anything.

They should return promises - even if they're promises for nothing, they still could be awaited.

But in your case, they actually *should* return something. Your global static `query` array is a horrible antipattern. Instead of filling it with queries, each method should return (a promise for) a query, which then can be passed to the executor on a per-instance and per-call basis. Only then using a *transaction* actually begins to make sense.

Your code should look like this:

```
class Main extends Component() {
  …
  async getBookable(){
    var response = await lfetch(host, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: …
    });
    var responseData = await response.json();
    return 'INSERT INTO bookable (data) VALUES (' + responseData + ')'); // beware of SQL injections!!!
  }

  getBooked(){
    // the very same - here written without async/await:
    return fetch(host, {
//  ^^^^^^ important - return a promise
      method: 'POST',
      headers: …
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(responseData => {
      return 'INSERT INTO booked (data) VALUES (' + responseData + ')';
    });
    // don't `catch` anything, don't call `done` - just return the promise chain
    // errors will be handled in the try/catch below
  }

  async runQuery(query) {
    await db.transaction(tx => {
      return Promise.all(query.map(async (q) => {
        try {
          let results = await tx.executeSql(q, []);
          console.log('Query', q, 'Executed. results:', results);
        } catch(err) {
          console.log('Something went wrong while executing query', q, 'error is', err);
        }
      }));
    });
    return true;
  }

  async function getStore() {
    try {
      // actually you can fetch these in parallel, right?
      let [bookable, booked] = await Promise.all([getBookable(), getBooked()]);
      let query = [bookable, booked];
      await runQuery(query);
      redirectUser();
    } catch(error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. i have updated last part of my question according to your answer. is that right way now?

Comment: Thanks a lot! i was just having a headache, 30 tabs open on my browser all talking different things! Thanks man!

Comment: I've updated my whole, it's a bit complicated. i've updated my question. could you please take a look at it , if it is in proper way?

Comment: @Ataomega `getBookable` does not seem to return a query (or an array thereof) any more. `getUsers` should not use `Promise.all(query.map(` if there is only a single query; similarly in `GrabData` it makes no sense to use `Promise.all` on a single-element array. And `GrabData` probably shouldn't call `runQuery` twice - why not do a single transaction? But if you are looking for more looks, you should post a new question at [codereview.SE] (assuming the code works) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) (otherwise). Please do not constantly change your question.

Comment: Thanks Bergi. i will do that